# What are some commonly used commands for Bitcoind shell command line?

Tags: bitcoind, linux

I just installed the bitcoind daemon on my ubuntu, but i was wondering what are some of the most commonly used commands for bitcoind?

Also is there a cheatsheet for this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the list of most common commands type

```
bitcoin-cli help
```

for a list of all commands refer to the [bitcoin client API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list).